# Ubuntu GPG keys shared accross multiple servers

Tags: php, ubuntu, gnupg

I have successfully set up our development server to send GPG encrypted emails from a PHP script. The user is asked for his/her public key which is then imported into GPG and a fingerprint is saved against this user for later encryption. All is well!

But now I need to deploy this onto the production servers - note multiple web servers - and this is putting me in a bit of a bother because I don't know how to share keys across them. To make this clearer, **user A** logs in on the website and **server #1** is used to serve the pages. He/she enters his/her public key which will be stored in the central database. Some time later, **user A** logs back in on the website but now is on **server #2**. An action is taken and an email is sent from **server #2** but no key can be found in the local GPG as it was saved on **server #1**.

So really my question is to ask which way is more suitable to achieve this, bearing in mind that I have 3 web servers at present + 1 central database server. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on all of them.
1) Should I export all the keys to a public place when I receive them? Is that safe/allowed or frowned upon?
2) Is there a mechanism to get the keys replicated on the other servers?
3) Can I use a central key repository on one of my servers?

Sorry if this sounds like a daft question - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using a very simple method.

Each time an email needs to be sent to a user with PGP enabled, the code will check whether the key has already been imported on the server using `--list-keys <signature>`. If this happens to be false then I just import the key as it is saved in the database.

Pretty robust as it is now, but I was looking for a more gpg-oriented type of solution.

Thanks